# count of updated objects using node mongodb native client

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I have the following update MongoDB query, run in Node.js via MongoDB native client. The query works correctly - I see objects being modified in my MongoDB after I run this code:

```
collection.update(
    {
      _id : request.query.person,
    },
    {
      $inc: {
        score : 1
      }
    },
    { safe : true},
    this /* "this" is for Step */
  );
```

I would like to know what is the number of records that were updated in MongoDB after my query. I have seen that I can do check it by running getLastError in MongoDB, but I am not sure how to do it from Node.js using the native client.

Any hints how to do it? Is there any other way than calling getLastError?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter to the `update` callback is the count of affected docs:

```
collection.update(
    { _id : request.query.person },
    { $inc: { score : 1 }},
    { safe : true},
    function (err, numAffected) {
        ...
    }
);
```

**Update** for the **2.x** version of the native driver:

The second parameter to the `update` callback is now a nested object, where the number of documents updated can be found in `result.nModified`. But `update` is now deprecated so [`updateOne`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#updateOne) should be used instead.

```
collection.updateOne(
    { _id : request.query.person },
    { $inc: { score : 1 }},
    { safe : true},
    function (err, response) {
        console.log(response.result.nModified);
        // Also available at response.modifiedCount for updateOne, but not update
        console.log(response.modifiedCount);
    }
);
```

The documentation for the 2.x callback parameters can be found [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#~writeOpCallback).